# Can't set text field to fill width in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-quick

I am following [this](https://youtu.be/9BcAYDlpuT8?t=561) tutorial on YouTube and the person sets the `TextField` to fill the width of the `RowLayout`. However, it doesn't seem to work for me. I tried using `Layout.fillWidth` on the `CheckBox` and it seems to work perfectly fine but it doesn't seem to want to work on the `TextField`. Here is my code:

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true;
    width: 640;
    height: 480;
    title: qsTr("Tabs");

    ToDoList
    {
        anchors.centerIn: parent;
    }
}
```

ToDoList.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Frame
{
    ListView
    {
        // Using implicit width and height allows the frame to automatically scale to the size of the list view
        implicitWidth: 250
        implicitHeight: 250
        clip: true
        model: 100
        delegate: RowLayout {
            width: parent.width

            CheckBox {}
            TextField
            {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what mine looks like

[image]

What did I do wrong?

I don't know if this has anything to do with it but I made a "Qt Quick Application - Swipe" instead of "Qt Quick Controls 2 Application" as that option wasn't available to me. Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit: I have written step by step instructions to replicate the issue below.**

1. File > New File or Project
2. From the new window make sure "Application" is selected then click "Qt Quick Application - Swipe" and press "Choose"
3. Set any name for the project and click "Next"
4. Set the build system to "qmake" and click "Next"
5. Set the minimal required Qt version to "Qt 5.9" and the Qt quick controls style to "Material Dark" and click "Next"
6. Select the "Desktop Qt 5.12.0 MSVC2017 64bit" as the kit and click "Next"
7. Set the options to have no version control and click "Finish"
8. Delete "Page1Form.ui.qml" and "Page2Form.ui.qml" from the "Projects" pane
9. Replace the contents of "main.qml" with:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true;
    width: 640;
    height: 480;
    title: qsTr("Tabs");

    ToDoList
    {
        anchors.centerIn: parent;
    }
}
```

10. Right click on the root project file and click "Add New"
11. From the new window make sure "Qt" is selected then click "QML File (Qt Quick 2)" and press "Choose"
12. Name the file "ToDoList" and click "Next"
13. Add to project "qml.qrc Prefix: /" then set the options to have no version control and click "Finish"
14. Replace the contents of "ToDoList.qml" with:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Frame
{
    ListView
    {
        // Using implicit width and height allows the frame to automatically scale to the size of the list view
        implicitWidth: 250
        implicitHeight: 250
        clip: true
        model: 100
        delegate: RowLayout {
            width: parent.width

            CheckBox {}
            TextField
            {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

15. Run the project

Comment: you could show an image of the error that you point out, in my case I have tried your code and I do not see the problem: https://imgur.com/a/eqqLShW

Comment: @eyllanesc this is what my project looks like: https://imgur.com/vpNWsIi

Comment: the code that shows does not generate what you show, as I observe from the image the Frame is inside another component, you could take the time to provide a correct **[mcve]**

Comment: I think that the Frame has a wider width than the ListView. and that's why I think that the TextField does not occupy all the space but in fact yes since the width of the ListView is not linked to the width of the Frame

Comment: add  `width: parent.width` inside of ListView: `ListView{  width: parent.width ...`

Comment: @eyllanesc I have added steps to replicate the issue. See if you get the same issue after following the steps. Also, adding width: parent.width to ListView did not work.

Comment: I get the following: https://imgur.com/a/yExbCrJ with Qt 5.12 on Linux

Comment: @eyllanesc Do you think it's the material dark theme which is causing this? Try setting the Qt quick controls style to Material Dark. Also I'm using Windows, I don't know if that has an effect.

Comment: okay, I just read what you mentioned about Material Style, and I confirm the behavior so the problem is caused by that Dark Material Style.

Comment: @eyllanesc Ok, thanks. How come the person in the Qt tutorial is able to do this without any issues? He is also using the material style except he doesn't have the options to select a dark theme.

Comment: I have not seen the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

The width is set properly. The problem is with `TextField` style. You may check it by setting background like

```
TextField
{
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    background: Rectangle {
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

Or just start typing into those fields with and without `Layout.fillWidth: true`